# How to get the browser to navigate to URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, navigation

What is the best (correct, modern, cross-browser, safe) way to get a web browser to navigate to a URL of your choice using JavaScript?

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other question is about redirection.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related. The other question doesn't have this concise answer that clarified the solution to my problem.

Comment: Ensure you use the "http://" or "https://" prefix

Answer (score 1925, accepted):

This works in all browsers:

```
window.location.href = '...';
```

If you wanted to change the page without it reflecting in the browser back history, you can do:

```
window.location.replace('...');
```

Comment: Using `window.location = '...'` is a synonym of `window.location.href = '...'` - from [Window.location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Comment: If you want to avoid reloading the whole page (though that would not technically be considered a navigation), look into history.pushState and history.replaceState.

Comment: If you want to simulate clicking on a link, use `location.href`   If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace`  Note that `location.replace` does not keep the originating page in the session history.

Comment: you should also mention `window.location.assign('...')`, which is functionally equivalent to `window.location.href = '...'`.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use `target="_blank"` with `window.location.href`? What if I also wanted to use `rel="noopener noreferrer"`? (I can't use an `<a>` tag.)

Answer (score 146):

Try these:

1. `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';`
2. `window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com");`
3. `window.location = 'http://www.google.com';`

For more see this link: [other ways to reload the page with JavaScript](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html)

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it explained the difference between the three. Also, please refer to 'Provide context for links' at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, because the link doesn't provide any more info, either.

Comment: If you are using TestCafe with Node.js then you could also do: `await t.navigateTo('http://www.google.com');`

Comment: `location.assign` worked in my case, thank you :)

Comment: is there a way to wait for the page to full load after any of these or similar calls? e.g. if I run this in Chrome Console, only last page (google) ever truly loads 
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com");
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';

Comment: `document.location = "...";
document.location.href ="..." ;
document.location.assign("...");
document.location.replace("....");` can also be used.

Answer (score 65):

It seems that this is the correct way `window.location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp
- https://web.archive.org/web/20150307183711/https://jstricks.com/javascript-redirect-page-redirection/

Comment: Good documentation but it says that the assign function doesn't save the current address in the history and thats something to consider. There is no correct or incorrect way, depends on the programmer's needs

Comment: @OrBetzalel, I believe the assign function DOES save the current address in the browser's history (though of course that could vary across browsers).

See discussion at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location, where it explains that `window.location.replace()` does NOT save the current address in history, but makes no such mention of `window.location.assign()`.

In my own testing with Chrome (current Mac version as of Oct 2019), `window.location.assign()` DOES save the current address in the browser's history.

Comment: In my own testing with Chrome (current Mac version as of  April 2023), window.location.assign() DOES NOT save the current address in the browser's history.