# Get browser to redirect window from modalized content

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, modal-dialog

I have content in a modalized window, and when a user clicks a link, I'd like to have the entire browser redirect, not just the modal window.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript) doesn't work, unfortunately.

Code I currently have:

```
<a onclick="window.location.href = 'http://insert/url/here'">morestuff!</a>
```

This only loads the url in the modal window.  What can I do to get the whole window to load said url?

Comment: Do you have a sample of how your content is being loaded in the model window? Is it via an iframe or loaded in via ajax etc?

Comment: Via Modalizer, a Joomla! extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<a onclick="window.parent.location.href='http://insert/url/here'">morestuff!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "modalized" - do you mean a jquery dialog/IFrame window or a physically different browser window.

If it's the first case then you need a reference to the outer parent:

window.parent.location.href = "http://www...";

If it's the second one then you need a reference to the opener:

window.opener.location.href = "http://www...";