# go to url if div has certain bg image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if a div has a certain background image, and if it has the image, then the page should navigate to a url.

However, I can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong?

```
case key.enter:
    if (letterIndex == 0 && $(this).hasClass('active')) {
           $(this).prev().remove();
    } else if ($('.content').css("background-image") === "url(img/screen-check.jpg)") { 
            // go to url
    }  else {
            $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Can you give jsfiddle sample code?

Comment: Is your question the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript

Comment: working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/870oz2gv/1/)

Comment: @JamesNewton Not really, I know how to navigate to url, but I want to do the navigation only if the div has a certain image.

Comment: your comparison works in principle: [https://jsfiddle.net/govi20/u37cxxbh/](https://jsfiddle.net/govi20/u37cxxbh/)
There must be something wrong with the parenting checks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if below code works. Please try and let me know

```
 case key.enter:
        if (letterIndex == 0 && $(this).hasClass('active')) {
               $(this).prev().remove();
        } else if ($('.content').css("background-image") &&$('.content').css("background-image").indexOf('img/screen-check.jpg') >-1 ) { 
                // go to url
        }  else {
                $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
        }
        break;
```

Comment: @jdo Can you please tell me what is the value of $('.content').css("background-image") ? Are you sure that if loop is getting executed?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the if statement is executed at all.