# Change countdown expiration from text to redirect

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript countdown timer that displays text when it expires. I would like to have it redirect to a different URL instead. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can alter the code to achieve this? Your help is appreciated...

```
expire: function(idxs){
for(var x in idxs) {
this.display(this.counts[idxs[x]], "Your timer is expired...");
this.counts.splice(idxs[x], 1);
}
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a redirect inside your expire function.

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `window.location.href = ...`.

Please see this question: [How to get browser to navigate to URL in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript)