# Going to a URL using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to go to a URL like this:

```
methods: {
    show (file) {
        this.$router.go('/file/' + file.path + '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('jwt-token'));
    }
}
```

I'm not trying to go to a component. I just want to go to the following URL:

```
'/file/' + file.path + '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('jwt-token')
```

But it does not work. It's redirecting me to the home page.

How can I get this done?

Comment: vue router 1 or 2?

Comment: Did you find out? Any of the answers below helped you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to go to a URL which is not a Vue router URL, you can do it using standard javascript via:

```
window.location.href = '/file/' + file.path + '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('jwt-token');
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1226718/2418066).

Comment: I use vue2. This answer doesn't work on me. This still gets me to homepage. For example, window.location.href = "www.gotosite.com" forwards me to http://example.com/www.gotosite.org

Comment: @noypee this is because your should put `https://` in front of your URL otherwise it just goes to a relative URL

Answer (score 1):

This should work in vue router 2.0:

```
this.$router.push({path: '/file/' + file.path , query: {token: localStorage.getItem('jwt-token')} })
```