# HTML Javascript $_post response shows the PHP header location page and not forwarding

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html code which sends the input to the PHP where the php redirect to a login page.

But when i do the post request as bellow, it gives a response back to the javascript; with the forwarding index.html code without redirect to the index.html.

```
<script>
        function Sendmeaway() {
            var item_i = document.getElementById("item_select").value;

            if (item_i == "Initial_Value") {
                alert("Please Select the Correct Option or Enter the Comment");
            } else {
                $.post("./back_p/add_change_req.php", {
                        item : item_i
                    },
                    function(data, textStatus) {
                        alert("Response from server: " + data);
                        document.getElementById("item_select").selectedIndex = 0;
                        location.reload();
                    });
            }

        };
    </script>
```

PHP code (it works fine when i go directly to the php)

> `<?php echo $_POST["item"]; header('location: ../index.html'); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect users like that. `AJAX` calls can only send and recieve data.

Instead redirect the user using `window.location.href = ''` in the success function of your `AJAX` call.

So instead of

```
<?php echo $_POST["item"]; header('location: ../index.html'); ?>
```

Do

```
<?php echo $_POST["item"]; return '../index.html'; ?>
```

Then use that returned value inside your `script` like:

```
function(data, textStatus) {
    alert("Response from server: " + data);
    document.getElementById("item_select").selectedIndex = 0;

    window.location.href = data; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make an ajax call you need to change the page on javascript side [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-the-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript). You can send 0 or 1 from php to decide redirecting or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using php header, use a `<meta>` tag outside the PHP tag

Such as:

```
<?php

echo($_POST["item"]);

?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='../Index.html'" />
```

replacing the 5 after `content="` to however many seconds you want until the redirect executes