# How to loop 2 html pages periodically

Tags: html, dashboard

I have 2 static html webpage generated by our production software.
I want to make a dashboard to the shopfloor witch periodically change between this two pages. Is it possible with with ajax or javascript?

Comment: please add code or error log

Comment: @SubinBabu it seems like he's just looking for guidance, i posted a pretty simple answer to his question. It isn't fancy but it should lead him in the right direction.

Comment: StackOverflow is not for guidance.If you try something and got an error, then you can seek help for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure HTML Example**

To automatically switch between two web pages put this in between your `<head>` tag on one page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=page1.html">
```

Put this in between your `<head>` tag on the other page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=page2.html">
```

5 is the number of seconds to wait before loading the specified URL.  Change the URL to fit your pages.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in the first file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){location.href="url.to.the.second.page";},10 * 1000); </script>
```

and in the second file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){location.href="url.to.the.first.page";},10 * 1000); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you could do some type of JavaScript setTimeout() or setInterval() call in a Javascript function [JS Timing events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Personally I would probably use jQuery to manage it and do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(pageSwitchFunction, millisecondsIntervalToSwitchPages);
});

function pageSwitchFunction(){
// page swtich logic here
}
```

[Here's how to navigate to other pages using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-the-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript)

[Here's a quick jQuery intro](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)