# Can't click anchor tag using click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want instead of pressing the link of the `anchor tag` to load the page in `href` attributre I want the `anchor` invisible for the user, and clickable via the button provided.

This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("button").click(function(){
          $("a").click();
       });

  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
 <a href="http://www.touchwand.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Icons-and-backgrounds.zip"></a>
 <button >Button1</button>
</body>
```

If I click directly on the anchor I get to the URL, but via button it doesnt work. Why is not `<a>` clicked by the `click()` function? Why is it not working?

Comment: Try to use something like [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro - `preventDefault` isn't necessary here, the button isn't in a form.

Comment: `$("button").click(function(){
     window.location = $('a').attr('href');     
});`

Answer (score -1):

Which device did you test it on?
On mobile devices you have to get an initial user interaction to be able to execute Javascript.

You could also do something like:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    window.location.href = $("a")[0].href;
}
```

Would this help?
Can you provide more information?

Ref: [How to get the browser to navigate to URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-the-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript#1226718)