# Page just reloads but doesn't redirect to the page

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to set a button to redirect to home page, but the page is just refreshing and not redirecting to the home page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function backs(){
        location.replace("index.php");  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-the-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript

Comment: @Keutelvocht  still not working

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to redirect from a file in a deeper folder?
For instance index.php is in the root of the project but your button is in a file inside the a folder like folder/page.html. In that case you need to use ../index.php. This is called directory traversal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: you have to use , `window.location.replace...`

Comment: @SandrinJoy not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `location.href` instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function backs(){
        location.href = "index.php";  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is it a Javascript error? It can break your whole JS. Maybe you have to fix this first.

Comment: Test your function call: write `conosle.log(0)` into `backs()`. You should see a 0 in the console when klick the button. Do you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221137/discussion-between-govi-boy-and-kmgt).

Answer (score 1):

in your button add the `onClick` event as following :

```
<button onClick="javascript:window.location.href='index.php">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the button code? Both the HTML and JS? I'm curious how you are calling the `backs()` function.

Also, as others suggested, `location.href` would be more appropriate.

Comment: <button onClick="javascript:window.location.href='index.php'">Back</button>

Comment: if you are doing this then your `backs()` function isn't called when you click this button. Try `<button onClick="javascript:window.location='index.php'">Back</button>`

Comment: Also, see if you need to use `/index.php` vs just `index.php`