# how to close browser's current tab using javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
  win.close();
```

Comment: That would close the window you opened. Modern browsers locked down closing of windows. If you do not create the window/tab, you are most likely not going to be be closing it.

Comment: is there any way to close the current tab without using it anymore ?

Comment: See [`Window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close). What exactly are your expectations? What's not working? See [ask].

Comment: i want to close the current tab but when i use window.close() the browser says ` Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them `. I tried searching on google and tried everything but still got the error

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74513427/how-to-close-browsers-current-tab-using-javascript#comment131534834_74513427) @NhấtTiếuNạiHà Instead of opening a new window and closing the current one, just [reuse the current one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1226718/438273).

Comment: @jsejcksn I mean I don't need to open a new tab, just close the current tab

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is not possible.

Comment: You can not close windows you did not create.  As I said, browsers do not allow it.