# creation of custom widget in thingsboard v 3.5.1

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

i want a widget with 2 button only for navigation purpose
' button 1 ' is using for navigating to next dashboard &
' button 2' is using for previous dashboard

*So basically this same widget will make it for all dashboard

```
i want to make navigation to Next dashboard & Previous dashboard using this widget
```

So how to set predefined dashboard id & state for button 1&2 for this widget present in all dashboard

Java script Code used in static type widget that i used before , but not working

```
self.onInit = function() {
     var $injector = self.ctx.$scope.$injector;
    var utils = $injector.get(self.ctx.servicesMap.get('utils'));

    // Define the widget's HTML content with two buttons
    var widgetHtml = `
        <div>
            <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
            <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
        </div>
    `;

    // Append the HTML content to the widget container
    self.ctx.$container.html(widgetHtml);

    // Add click event listeners to both buttons
    var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
    var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

    button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Define the action for Button 1
        onButton1Click();
    });

    button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Define the action for Button 2
        onButton2Click();
    });

    function onButton1Click() {
      var dashboardId = 'e17bff10-48be-11ee-97d6-3bce35380cb4'; // dashboard ID
      console.log('button 1 clicked');
        self.ctx.navigationApi.navigateToDashboard(dashboardId);
    }

    function onButton2Click() {
        
        console.log('Button 2 clicked');
    }
}

self.onDestroy = function() {
    // Perform any cleanup when the widget is destroyed
};
actual
```

i am a beginner in thingsboard your support will help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Considering your are not taking data from one dashboard to another, that could be accomplished with any navigation instruction

Be that [JS native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-the-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript) like:

```
window.location.assign(`https://example.com/dashboards/${e17bff10-48be-11ee-97d6-3bce35380cb4}`)
```

Or using a more thingsboard/Angular way:

```
self.ctx.router.navigateByUrl(`https://example.com/dashboards/${e17bff10-48be-11ee-97d6-3bce35380cb4}`)
```

As used by the Navigation Card widget in the [component specification](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/ui-ngx/src/app/modules/home/components/widget/lib/navigation-card-widget.component.ts).

Hope being of help.

Comment: Yes , its working . Thank you for your valuable feedback @andresrokp